# How to print lines from file a file in a way of sequence i.e. sorted on basis of a specific column inside tcl script?

Tags: awk, sort, tcl

I want to print the file content based on sorting the 3rd column of sourcefile.

sourcefile.txt:

```
Manav Kumaom Fre
shailesh himadri aif
manisha Kailash mac
Ravi Jwala blu
Prakash Ojha Zan
Mahi Aulakh yep
```

I want to print the file content sorted on the basis of 3rd column in a new file:

Required output:

```
shailesh himadri aif
Ravi Jwala blu
Manav Kumaom Fre
manisha Kailash mac
Mahi Aulakh yep
Prakash Ojha Zan
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify: i) what operating system are you using, ii) did you try `sort`? This is what it's for, did it not work? What part of this is giving you problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
sort -k3 sourcefile.txt
```

- `-k` to sort with the key position/field.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl)

```
set filename "sourcefile.txt"
set fh [open $filename r]
set data [split [read -nonewline $fh] \n]
close $fh
set sorted [lsort -index 2 -dictionary $data]
puts [join $sorted \n]
```

That sorts by the 3rd word of each line (`-index 2`) in dictionary order -- I'm assuming that each line is a valid list. That may be naive: this would be safer:

```
set lines [split [read -nonewline $fh] \n]
set data [lmap line $lines {split $line}]
```

output

```
shailesh himadri aif
Ravi Jwala blu
Manav Kumaom Fre
manisha Kailash mac
Mahi Aulakh yep
Prakash Ojha Zan
```